# PHP method Failure

Tags: php, function, quickbooks

I have some methods which are used to access database values.
If I run a method on null value it gives and error which is what is suppose to happen, however I want to put in condition where even if the function fails it should proceed to next row inside database.

```
$i=0;
foreach($data as $Data){
   $fax = $Data->getFax()->getFreeFormNumber();
   echo $i." Fax no. of Customer ".$fax;
   $i++;
}
```

Output is:-

1. Fax no. of Customer 5678
2. Fax no. of Customer 9899
3. Fax no. of Customer 7777

However database has 19 rows and 5th row has a Fax no. in the database and 4th row Fax no. is empty(null)

How to get the code print the 5th row.? What condition do I need to put in.?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check wether `getFax` returns `null` before calling the `getFreeFormNumber()`. An example on how that can be achieved is below.

```
$i=0;
foreach($data as $Data){
   $fax = $Data->getFax();
   if(null === $fax){
        continue; // No fax so continue to the next item
   }

   echo $i." Fax no. of Customer ".$fax->getFreeFormNumber();
   $i++;       
}
```

To make it even more failsafe, repeat the check for the result from `getFreeFormNumber()`. Then you can be sure you are not dealing with `null` values.

Perhaps `getFax()` should even return a certain type of object/class, in that case change `null === $fax` to `!($fax instanceOf <theClassName>)`. That way you make sure you get the fax object which has the function you are going to call.

Comment: Also worth nothing that the library you're using supports getting this data via XPath, in which case you wouldn't need to do all of this null checks. e.g.  $val = $Customer->getXPath('//Customer/Fax/FreeFormNumber');

Answer (score 0):

You could use `isset` for example:

```
if (isset($faxNo)){
    echo $faxNo;
}else {
    echo "null";
}
```